# Do we have any evidence that there were plans for an Ankh-Morpork Underground?

Tags: discworld

I'm going to have to add details and quotes later for this as I don't currently have access to the books, but I remember noticing some things I thought were foreshadowing for an underground system in the later AM Discworld novels. In Thud, a large system of underground tunnels with rails was developed by the dwarves and then abandoned, and the Moist von Lipwig arc all dealt with major infrastructure developments (banking, postal services, railways). Do we have any evidence that Terry Pratchett had plans for, or even started writing, a book concerning the development of an underground railway system for Ankh Mopork?

(Before asking I Googled this and noted that [someone over on the LSpace wiki came to the same conclusion](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Undertaking), but the page doesn't cite any sources from the Pratchett estate.)

Comment: It's worth noting that any works in progress were, as per his wishes, quite comprehensively destroyed last year - https://www.theguardian.com/books/2017/aug/30/terry-pratchett-unfinished-novels-destroyed-streamroller. The person most likely to be able to give a definitive answer would be Rob Wilkins.

Comment: @adrianwragg I remember - sad, but I can understand his wishes. But just so nobody views this as a reason to close, I'd point out that this is still answerable with evidence that such work existed, even though it would now be gone.

Comment: It's answerable *if* it was planned *and* someone close to him said it was being planned. If he hadn't planned it, on the other hand, there would be no evidence - and lack of evidence is not evidence. So don't hold your breath on getting an answer, but I'd see no solid reason to close either.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I mostly agree with this, but I would for example consider a list of planned future projects failing to mention this to be acceptable evidence that it was not planned (even though he could theoretically have had a vague concept but not told anyone or written it down).

Comment: Check the foreword (?) to *The Shepherd's Crown*.  It mentioned a few of the planned future works, IIRC.

Comment: I've read allusions to this (models by drumknott and leo dQ, etc) but it was in some (very good) fanfiction.

Comment: If I recall it correctly, in "Making Money" Vetinari speaks of needing a new finance system for funding Undertaking (?). The way it was talked about left me an impression that it *was* related to Underground.

Comment: I noticed this article from 2007 says "Because even though Making Money is the 36th Discworld novel, Pratchett isn't resting on his laurels. *Just as Lord Vetinari is beginning the Undertaking to modernise Ankh-Morpork with underground railways*, so is Pratchett refreshing his series", so I feel like there must be more about this somewhere... https://amp.theguardian.com/books/2007/sep/29/fiction.terrypratchett

Comment: Sadly lacking sources, but from the Wikipedia page on Vetinari: "At some point between Thud! and Making Money, Vetinari begins planning for a phenomenal redevelopment project of Ankh Morpork titled 'The Undertaking' – this seems to have been inspired by the discovery in Thud! of an ancient perpetual motion engine – a twin of one which according to Carrot Ironfoundersson powers all of the machinery in one of the largest mines in Uberwald. Rumours around the Undertaking include mention of 'underground streets', 'waterproof tunnels' and 'new docks'." https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Vetinari

Comment: Closest yet to evidence that Vetinari, at least, had plans in this direction (whether Pterry planned a book about them or not): 'He has plans for the city, you know.' 'The Undertaking,' said Moist. 'Yes, I know.' 'Underground streets and new docks and everything,' said Topsy (Making Money, p51)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is almost certainly unanswerable. The only information we have about unwritten Discworld novels is a footnote to The Shepherd's Crown by Rob Wilkins:

> We will not know how the old folk of *Twilight Canyons* solve the mystery of a missing treasure and defeat the rise of a Dark Lord despite their failing memories, nor [... other non-Underground stuff elided]. And these are just a few of the ideas his office and family know about.

In accordance with Pterry's wishes, the hard disk containing his unpublished material was destroyed after his death. Unless a member of "his office and family" choose to disregard the spirit, if not the letter, of that aspect of his will and share his unpublished ideas posthumously, they will remain unknown.

Comment: I just realised that the question in the title was not the same as the question in body - the former was probably unanswerable, this answers the second. Now edited to match. I'll leave it open for a day or two in case anyone else has anything to add but it seems pretty conclusive.